# Pyinstaller, only packing part of the employed third-party packages, and calling the remaining on another PC

Tags: python, pyinstaller

1. On PC1, I have a program in which package A B C is employed, and I'd
   like to pack the program by Pyinstaller together with package A B
   (excluding C for some reason), obtaining "main.exe".
2. Assuming that there's another machine PC2 installed with python and
   package C, I hope to run this "main.exe" (without package C
   embedded) on PC2, during which package C installed on PC2 is called.

Is this realizable? and How?

I pack the program on PC1 by:`pyinstaller main.py --exclude-module C` and as expected, failing to execute main.exe on PC2 with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C'`, since package C installed on PC2 can not be recognized by main.exe.

To be precise, Package C mentioned refers to "geatpy" [http://geatpy.com](http://geatpy.com/), Package A, B refer to Numpy, Pandas, xlwt, etc. Bundling all of these into one bundle and running it, some errors occur:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    from optimization import *  
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "optimization.py", line 20, in <module>
    import geatpy as ea  
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "geatpy\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awGA'
[48140] Failed to execute script main
```

After enquiring with the developer of this module, he suggests excluding this module in the bundle, and install via pip cmd instead, because pyinstaller may be not well compatible with pyd/dll file. I am quite new to coding, so maybe I can't get his point or there may be some misunderstanding.

Comment: Can you elaborate what's the purpose of all of this? It will help us understand what your reasoning for this is. It feels like bit contradictory - i.e. if you bundle it so you can easily distribute as one bundle, incl. the interpreter and avoid installing packages. In your setup it feels much more natural to build a whl, install it + dependencies.

Comment: @buran I supplement the questions above, thx.

Comment: As I suspected this is XY problem. The most likely reason for missing import is that `pyinstaller` is not able to detect it is needed and must be included in the bundle. Check https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#helping-pyinstaller-find-modules The most simple thing to try is to explicitly declare the package as hidden import - using `--hidden-import` or by editing the `spec` file.

Comment: And in any case, if you are going to install `geatpy` separately on the target machine, it is better to distribute your code as python package (i.e. build whl), and when install it, it will download and install all dependencies (i.e. numpy, pandas, xlwt, geatpy, etc.) instead of building some crippled exe.

Comment: OK, I will do some learning and have a try.

Comment: @buran I have figured it out, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution by manually copy all the .pyd file in folder `Python38\Lib\site-packages\geatpy` into the pyinstaller-produced folder `dist\main`, and I do it the same way for several other missed .py modules warned during execution.

To generate the `dist\main` folder, `pyinstaller -c main.py` is applied instead of bundling it into one executable file.

As **buran** say, the missing import problem is due to the inability of pyinstaller to detect what is needed, especially for .pyd file.

I try some other arguments for pyinstaller but fails, like: `--paths=....` `--hidden-import=geatpy`. Maybe that's the limitation of pyinstaller.

For the second suggestion of **buran**, I haven't tried it yet, but it's believed to be feasible.